# Point Out Response Entity

Tags: java, api, exception

I'm trying to create an exception handling inside a getByStudyType method but I cant since ResponseEntity is not a type so, I tried using try-catch block inside controller class but failed, any help is appreciated

Controller class

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Read a study by study-name")
@GetMapping("/studies/{studyType}")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getByStudyType(@ApiParam(value = "Questionnaire StudyType will retrieve", required = true) @PathVariable("studyType") String studyType) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(repository.getByStudyType(studyType), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Service class

```
public Map<String, Object> getByStudyType(String studyType) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Item item = table.getItem("studyType", studyType);
            map.putAll(item.asMap());
            System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
        } catch (ApiRequestException ex) {
            throw new ApiRequestException("Study type cannot be found");
        }
        return map;
    }
```

When I test this on Postman, I got this response, you see the message is not there

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-10-09T03:17:33.655+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/studies/Migraness"
}
```

Comment: `ResponseEntity` is a **type**, not a variable, so a test of  `ResponseEntity == null` makes no sense.  Probably what you need to be testing is the return from `repository.getByStudyType(studyType)`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson well I did that but Postman is giving me a "No message is available" and 500 error status

Comment: Is the "service class" your repository?  Are we seeing a snippet of code from the `getByStudyType` method?

Comment: I suspect `table.getItem("studyType", studyType)` is returning `null` when it doesn't find the specified item; then `item.asMap()` causes a `NullPointerException`.  Instead you should be detecting the not-found condition and returning a suitable indication back to the controller.  But also the controller should be checking for that indication and returning an appropriate response.